# Finding the MySQL binlog positions to restore replication

Tags: replication, mysql-5.7, mysqldump

I have a large database where replication became broken (a query to delete rows ran on the slave directly by mistake)

The decision was taken to restore the slave from the master. I've made an export using `mysqldump`, copied to the slave server, and the import is running, now at 25% (guesstimate).

Unfortunately I lost the note where I captured the binlog position from `SHOW MASTER STATUS` which I will need to restart replication. (I smartly rebooted my PC without saving the note)

Option A - Find a way to figure out the binlog position using a combination of the binlog files that are present on the master and the dump file timestamp. How ? - if this is possible it would help a lot.

Option B - start over and include `--master-data=1` in the `mysqldump` output.

I've started the process on the master to create a new dump file with this option - the export will run for about 18 hours and the copy over the network takes about 2 hours.

The import takes around 3 days. I do not yet know how long it will take to catch up 4 days worth of logs, but probably a day or so.

My main question is whether I can save the currently running import by gleaning the binlog position information from the data that I have?

Failing that I need to cancel this import and get a new export.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up cancelling the import and starting over, this time SAVING the note where I pasted the binlog coords.